# How to populate all days of the year in just one query?

Tags: mysql

I would like to populate my table tblRemarks having 6 columns name,  date, remarks, total_absents, remarks_information, Section

I have data in my columns which is

```
NAME         DATE      TOTAL_ABSENTS     REMARKS   REMARKS_INFORMATION     SECTION

lemich   3/2/2016         5            absent         CUTTING CLASSES         3A

pablo    3/2/2016         6            absent         CUTTING CLASSES         3A

lemich   3/3/2016         5           ________         ___________            3A

pablo    3/3/2016         6           ________         ___________            3A
```

I want to produce the output

```
NAME         DATE      TOTAL_ABSENTS     REMARKS   REMARKS_INFORMATION     SECTION

lemich   3/2/2016         5            absent         CUTTING CLASSES         3A

pablo    3/2/2016         6            absent         CUTTING CLASSES         3A

lemich   3/3/2016         5           ________         ___________            3A

pablo    3/3/2016         6           ________         ___________            3A

lemich   3/4/2016         5           ________         ___________            3A

pablo    3/4/2016         6           ________         ___________            3A

lemich   3/5/2016         5           ________         ___________            3A

pablo    3/5/2016         6           ________         ___________            3A

lemich   3/6/2016         5           ________         ___________            3A

pablo    3/6/2016         6           ________         ___________            3A 
and so on....
```

meaning I would like to make an insert statement where I can populate all days of the year with just one query.

note(remarks should be null)

Comment: Can you add an example of how the resultant data should look like?

Answer (score 1):

write you insert query then select this query

```
SET @count := 0;
SET @TOTAL_ABSENTS := 5;
SET @REMARK := NULL;
select CONCAT(@count := @count+1,'.', 'lemich') AS NAME, date_format(selected_date,'%m/%d/%Y') AS `DATE`, @TOTAL_ABSENTS AS TOTAL_ABSENTS, @REMARK AS REMARK from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31';
```

This is return all days of 2016

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aa76)

Comment: what does union mean? can you briefly explain your codes to me?

Comment: UNION is used to combine the results of 1 query with another. In this case it is used to get 10 rows with the numbers 0 to 9 in them. this is done 5 times (as t0 to t4), giving every combination of 0 to 9 5 times. This is used to generate a list of numbers between 0 and 99999. This number is added as days to a start date of 1970/01/01, giving a large range of dates, then the WHERE clause is used to select the ones between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' that you are interested in.

Comment: i just edidted my questions. can you please do that for me?

Comment: yes you are right. if you remove the where clause then it will return all date.

Comment: you can use union for that output and wrap up in one query use order by date

Comment: if i am using visual basic that is connected to mysql can i insert that query inside a function?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on EXACTLY what you want inserted (eg, do you want to fill the rest of the year, a year from the latest date, etc) then the exact needs change.

This will add 365 days worth of rows to the latest date for each name. The section value is just a random one for each name, but you haven't specified whether there are more than one per name and if so which one to chose.

Not tested but here you go

```
INSERT INTO tblRemarks(`name`, date, total_absents, remarks, remarks_information, section)
SELECT sub_names.`name`, 
        DATE_ADD(sub_names.max_date, INTERVAL hundreds.i * 100 + tens.i * 10 + units.i + 1 DAY),
        sub_names.total_absents,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        a_section
FROM
(
    SELECT `name`, MAX(total_absents) AS total_absents, MAX(`date`) AS max_date, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(section), ',', 1) AS a_section
    FROM tblRemarks 
    GROUP BY `name`
) sub_names
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) units
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) tens
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 
) hundreds
WHERE hundreds.i * 100 + tens.i * 10 + units.i < 365
```

Comment: in my data i included a field with a section in it.
for example lemich(student_name) has a section (3b) i want the rest of the   newly inserted table will have a lemich with a section (3b)

Comment: Unknown column 'sub_names.name' in 'field list'

Comment: Probably because name is a mysql reserved word (I avoid ever using column names that are reserved words). I have edited the answer to add back tics around the field name. Can you post your actual table declare so I have some chance of testing it please?

Comment: i didnt used name i used student_name

Comment: can i just post a picture? of my actual table?

Comment: I would rather have the declaration as then I can copy and paste it in seconds rather than having to manually type it all in. If you have used the field name student_name, then that is what the sub query is returning, so other parts of the query that refer to it need changing as well